# "WHERE ... IN (...)" using pgx

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am using postgresql go client: github.com/jackc/pgx
I would like to execute SQL query looking a bit like this one:

```
ids := []int{2,3,4}
rows, err = pool.Query("SELECT id, title FROM document WHERE id IN ($1)", ids)
```

The result is a following error: `cannot convert [2 3 4] to Int8`

Can I achieve such effect without concatenating string like `id=$1 OR id=$2 OR....` ?

Comment: Postgres doesn't let you use a single identifier for a list.  It doesn't understand slices.  I've not use pgx, but I know sqlx specifically has a `In()` function to remap a slice to a list of args.  You can manually do this yourself, though, by replacing that `$1` with an iterative list of placeholders, akin to this: https://play.golang.org/p/C53TX6_KXP1